# how is this query done in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Given the following table ...

```
ID  USER  NUM
 1     1   69
 2     2   75
 3     3    7
 4     1   31
 5     2   18
 6     3   70
 7     1   12
 8     2   23
 9     3   42
```

... which query would return rows with the *lowest* NUM for each USER?

The result should look like ...

```
ID  USER  NUM
 7     1   12
 5     2   18
 3     3    7
```

Can't wrap my head around this one! Assuming it has a `GROUP BY`, but everything I try fails... Any pointers?

Comment: Do you also need to have a correspondent `id`? What if there are several rows with the same `num`?

Comment: what? you're trying to get to a query from a result?

Comment: yah.. just need the complete row for each USER with the lowest NUM

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple rows with the same minumum for the same user?

Comment: great question, but it wouldn't happen :)

Comment: @Mark Byers: how did you get that hat on your avatar?!?!?

Comment: @zerkms: Here in the northern hemisphere it is winter. You can't go without a hat in this weather!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, MIN(num) num
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user) x ON t.user = x.user AND t.num = x.num
```

or

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.num > t2.num
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: yep, `INNER JOIN` worked like a charm. my brain is a pretzel. thanks much!

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` works also, though it f**king baffles me how!
the `INNER JOIN` is about 15 times faster.

Comment: @neokio: yep, it's faster because `LEFT JOIN` solution generates almost `N*N` rows then cuts `N*(N-1)` of them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID , MIN(NUM) as MIN_NUM , USER FROM usertable GROUP BY USER
```

Have a look at demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce2fd/1

Comment: How would you get **correspondent** `id`?

Comment: No, this wont return **correspondent** id, it will return some random `id`

Comment: @zerkms Not true, that query won't even run.

Comment: @Anthony Grist: why? mysql isn't that strict (by default) ;-) It's sad but it allows this silly query :-)

Comment: @zerkms Ah, really? I don't use mysql myself, but having queries with essentially undefined behaviour seems like an... interesting... design choice.

Comment: @raheel shan: for `user = 1` the `num` should be `12` (correct) and `id` should be 7 (**INCORRECT**)

Comment: @Anthony Grist: yep, there is a strict mode that will switch the behaviour to the "right" one, but by default nonsense is possible ))

Answer (score 0):

HEre is another method. **UPDATED WITH THE CORRECT REREFERENCE**

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c8e7)

Query

```
select b.id, a.user, a.minnum from 
mytable as b
join 
(select user, min(num) as minnum
 from mytable
 group by user
) as a
on b.user = a.user
where b.num = a.minnum
order by a.minnum asc
limit 3
;
```

Results:

```
  ID    USER    MINNUM
3   3   7
7   1   12
5   2   18
```

Comment: What do you mean by "another"?

Comment: Sorry I have gotten the wrong reference here. You are fast :) +1 for that @zerkms I said another solution, because I am using `Limit 3`, plus `join` is enough as `left` is not necessarily the case here :)